# Error in passing a string between two forms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I am developing a windows forms application using C# and I am trying to pass a string from one form to another. My string seems to pass into the second form but however, when I try to display that string as a label on my second form, it does not display the string. However, when I try to display it in a message box on my second form, it displays the passed string inside the message box. How can I make changes to my code, so I can use the passed string to display as a label in my second form?

This is my code:

My form1 contains,

```
 private void Report_Bug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ReportForm newForm = new ReportForm();
        string myString = "Hello World!";// string to be passed
        newForm.AuthUser = myString; //sending the string to the second form
        newForm.Show();
    }
```

My form2(Reportform) contains,

```
public partial class ReportForm : Form
{
    public string AuthUser { get ; set; } //retrieving passed data

    public ReportForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        populateListBox();
        userlabel.Text = AuthUser; //setting the label value to "Hello World!" - This doesn't work
    }

    private void Report_Submit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(AuthUser);// This displays a message box which says "Hello World!" so the string is passed
    }
}
```

How can I make changes to my code so it the label "userlabel" will display the string that I passed from my first form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor on ReportForm is executed **before** you set the AuthUser property inside Report_Bug_Click.  You can solve this by passing the string directly to an overloaded constructor:

```
public ReportForm() {}

public ReportForm(string authUser)
{
    this.AuthUser = authUser
    InitializeComponent();
    populateListBox();
    userlabel.Text = this.AuthUser;
}
```

In your Form1 you pass the string in the constructor:

```
private void Report_Bug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportForm newForm = new ReportForm("Hello World!");
    newForm.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly. It even allows me to use the string outside of Reportform(). Once again, thank you very much :)

Answer (score 3):

You set the label text in Form before you set the AuthUser property. You could have ReportForm constructor accept the string.

```
public ReportForm(string labelText)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        populateListBox();
        userlabel.Text = labelText;
    }
```

Here I'm assuming you don't really need AuthUser anymore.

Comment: Can you please explain your answer little bit more

Comment: ReportForm() is your constructor, where you set the label. When you call new ReportForm, that is called and sets label. Then after that, you set AuthUser property.

Comment: How can I change my code, so it doesn't have this conflict

Comment: There are a lot of options. One I suggested is to have your constructor (ReportForm) accept a string parameter, which you then set to the label. You may not need the AuthUser property anymore in that case.

Answer (score 1):

The line `userlabel.Text = AuthUser;` should not be in `ReportForm()` method of your second form. It is the constructor of your class and it is executed before you assign `myString` to `newForm.AuthUser`. The easiest thing to do would be putting `userlabel.Text = AuthUser;` in an event handler like Form_Load(). You can also change the constructor to receive that string as a parameter and show it in the label.

Answer (score 1):

Or, using Andy's suggestion, pass the string as a parameter in the constructor:

```
    string myString = "Hello World!";// string to be passed
    ReportForm newForm = new ReportForm(myString);


public ReportForm(string text)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    populateListBox();
    userlabel.Text = text; 
}
```